# when $G$ acts properly discontinuously on riemann surface then the orbits are closed sets?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

could any one tell me how to prove: 
when $G$ acts properly discontinuously on riemann surface then the orbits are closed sets?
$G$ is the group of all homeomorphism on $X$ say.

so we have $f:G\times X\rightarrow X$ be a proper discont. action so $\forall x\in X   \exists V open$ containing $x$ $f(V)\cap V=\phi$
and orbit of $x$, $O_x=\{gx:g\in G\}$

we need to show $O_x$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $G$ acts properly discontinously iff $\forall x\in X$ the orbit is locally finite.

let the orbit has a limit point $p\in X$ then by local compactness there would exist a compact set containing $p$ that does not satisfy the locally finite condition.